# Indexed field + limit 1 vs. Unique field comparison in terms of performance | MySQL

Tags: mysql, performance, indexing

**Example 1.** Field `c.alias` is unique.

```
Select c.* from category c where c.alias = 'some-alias'
```

**Example 2.** Field `c.alias` is simply indexed.

```
Select c.* from category c where c.alias = 'some-alias' limit 1
```

Does these two examples differ in terms of query performance?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is to test and find out.

If there is a difference, however, I would expect it to be very, very minor.  In both cases, the `where` clause should use an index.  You are really asking whether MySQL "knows" to stop after the first match (because of the unique index).  Or will MySQL need to look at the next value to see that it is different.  This second step would have very little overhead.

I would also offer that if this is a serious question about optimizing code, then you are probably looking in the wrong place.  Such micro-optimizations (perhaps nano- in this case) are not usually helpful.

I should note that if you were comparing a *primary key* index to a regular index, you might see a measurable difference.  In MySQL, a primary key is automatically clustered and that could be a (small but measurable) performance difference.

Comment: Okay. Does Primary key comparing to a Unique key has the same measurable difference?

Comment: Thank you, Gordon!

Answer (score 1):

(Gordon's answer is good.  But I have a few different things to say...)

`SELECT ... WHERE unique_col = constant` -- This will read one row (if any) from the table.  `LIMIT 1` has no impact other than the trivial parsing time.

`SELECT ... WHERE non_uniq_col = constant` -- This will read until it finds a row that does not match.  That is, it will read N+1 rows to deliver N rows.  For this case, `LIMIT 1` would stop it short.  Now the question is not about performance (not much difference if N is small), but about functionality (did you want 1 row or N).

In InnoDB, the `PRIMARY KEY` is "clustered" with the data, and is implicitly `UNIQUE`.  So it is as described above.

With a *secondary* key, there is an extra step.  First the row(s) is found (`col=const`) in the *index* BTree.  At the leafnode of that BTree is the PK for the desired row.  The extra step is to drill down the PK's BTree to find the row.  This costs some extra, but is rarely worth worrying about for small-to-medium-sized tables.  (The `LIMIT 1` issues still apply, and are minor.)

If *all* the columns referenced in the `SELECT` are in the same secondary index (including the implicit copy of the PK), then the index is said to be "covering".  Hence, the query can be performed entirely in the secondary index's BTree, thereby avoiding the extra step.  Again, this is usually small, but may be worth doing.  "Covering" is indicated in `EXPLAIN` by "Using index" (not "Using index condition", which refers to something different).

May I suggest you study my [*Indexing Cookbook*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql) rather than learn the gory details first.  My document gives you the important things for performance, and leaves out some of the less important details, such as what this question is discussing.

For *tiny* tables in a low-volume project, none of this matters.
For *huge* tables, the number of disk hits is the main performance metric; minimizing that becomes the goal.  In particular, the extra step for secondary indexes usually involves N disk hits (for N rows).

But...  `SELECT ... GROUP BY ... ORDER BY ... LIMIT 1` may involve fetching a bunch of rows, sorting them, and finally delivering 1 row.  *If* the sorting cannot be consumed in the index, N rows are manipulated, perhaps multiple times.  In *this* case, `LIMIT 1` is acted on only after 99% of the effort was expended.  This is a common misconception about `LIMIT` for novices.